# Why does angular ui-router reloads the page even when reloadOnSearch is false in html5Mode?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular application and I use **ui-router** not in **html5Mode** so the links are like these:

```
example.com/#/dashboard
example.com/#/about
example.com/#/products?id=12
```

in products page I have **reloadOnSearch** is set to **false** and when I change **id** search param directly from url bar it doesn't reload the page and I handle that by **$locationChangeSuccess** event and it works well for me.

The problem now is that after I changed my app to **html5Mode** and the links became like these:

```
example.com/dashboard
example.com/about
example.com/products?id=12
```

Everything is good, but when I change **id** search param the page is being reloaded entirely even when I have **reloadOnSearch** set to **true**

Any suggestions to prevent reloading?

Comment: Are you changing the URL manually, by typing in the location field?

Comment: yes, but just search param which is **id** in my example